# Inserting Multiple rows in mysql using codeigniter : it inserts only one row and in that one row stores only one first character

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I tried to insert multiple rows in sql . But it inserts only the last one row and in that one row only storing first character of each column. I prints the query by echo, it shows only one last row, but gives all characters of each column. one more thing is iam inserting values in two tables by clicking on submit button. can anyone help on this.

**Here it is the view :**

```
    <form class="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>dashboard/addnewjobmela" >

                        <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="LgVIVf7yFe5bL9k2Rcj9TGLLpgKJX1LkmfiiptEZnN95y9WqKXHk7V4vGixmo6Wd">
                        <input type="hidden" id="cperson_no" value="1">
                        <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 ">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Job Mela Title</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="title"  required="" id="title">
                        </div>
                        </div>
                       <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Job Mela Date</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="date" name="date"  required="" id="date">
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Last Date To Register</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="date" name="laastdatetoregister"  required="" id="laastdatetoregister">
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 ">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Venue Details</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" name="venuedetails" cols="40" rows="2" required="" id="venuedetails"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 ">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Contact Person</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="contactperson"  required="" id="contactperson">
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 ">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Contact Emailid</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="emailid"  required="" id="emailid">
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 ">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Contact Number</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="contactnumber"  required="" id="contactnumber">
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row-fluid" >
                        <div style="background-color:#d6e9c6 !important;padding:10px"><p class="text-success"><b>Participating Companies</b></p></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 right" style="margin-top:-40px;margin-bottom: 20px">
                        <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="addingcompanies()">Add More</button>
                        </div>
                        <div id="companies">
                        <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 ">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Company Name</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="company"  required="" id="company">
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 ">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Job Title</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="jobtitle"  required="" id="jobtitle">
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 ">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Required Qualification</label>
                            <?php
                                echo form_dropdown('qualification', $education,'' ,'required="" class="form-control"');
                            ?>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 ">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Specialization</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="specialization"  required="" id="specialization">
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 ">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Sector</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="sector"  required="" id="sector">
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Job Type</label>
                            <?php
                                echo form_dropdown('jobtype', $jobtype,'' ,'required="" class="form-control"');
                            ?>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Company Logo</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="file" name="picture" accept=".jpeg,.JPEG,.JPG,.jpg,.png,.PNG" required="" id="id_picture">
                        </div>
                        </div> -->
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 ">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Job Location</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="joblocation"  required="" id="joblocation">
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-xs-12" style="text-align:center">
                            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Save Profile">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                    </form>
```

**Javascript/Jquery to add ADD More Fields**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function addingcompanies()
    {
      var cperson_no = $('#cperson_no').val();
                          var j=parseInt(cperson_no)+1;
                          $('#cperson_no').val(j);
        var qualification = '<?php echo str_replace("'", '', preg_replace("/\r|\n/", "", form_dropdown('qualification', $education,'' ,'required="" class="form-control"'))); ?>';
        var jobtype = '<?php echo str_replace("'", '', preg_replace("/\r|\n/", "", form_dropdown('jobtype', $jobtype,'' ,'required="" class="form-control"'))); ?>';
        $('#companies').append('<div class="row group"><hr/><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 "> <div class="form-group"> <label>Company Name</label> <input class="form-control" type="text" name="company" required="" id="company' + cperson_no + '"> </div></div><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 "> <div class="form-group"> <label>Job Title</label> <input class="form-control" type="text" name="jobtitle" required="" id="jobtitle' + cperson_no + '"> </div></div><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 "> <div class="form-group"> <label>Required Qualification</label> '+ qualification +'</div></div><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 "> <div class="form-group"> <label>Specialization</label> <input class="form-control" type="text" name="specialization" required="" id="specialization' + cperson_no + '"> </div></div><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 "> <div class="form-group"> <label>Sector</label> <input class="form-control" type="text" name="sector" required="" id="sector' + cperson_no + '"> </div></div><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4"> <div class="form-group"> <label>Job Type</label>'+jobtype+' </div></div><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 "> <div class="form-group"> <label>Job Location</label> <input class="form-control" type="text" name="joblocation" required="" id="joblocation' + cperson_no + '"> </div></div><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 "><button class="btn btn-danger" style="margin-top: 25px; !important;" type="button" onClick="con_grpremove(this)">Remove</button></div></div></div>');


    }
    function con_grpremove(obj) {
                                $(obj).closest(".group").remove();
                            }
</script>
```

**Here it is the controller :**

```
public function addnewjob()
        {

            $this->load->model('dashboard_model');
            $result = $this->dashboard_model->addnewjob();
            $this->session->msg = "New Job Added Successfully";
            redirect('dashboard');

        }
                public function addnewjobmela()
                {

                        $this->load->model('dashboard_model');
                        $result = $this->dashboard_model->addnewjobmela();
                        $this->session->msg = "New Job Mela Added Successfully";
                        redirect('dashboard');

                }
```

**Model :**

```
public function addnewjobmela() {
        $data['title'] = $this->input->post('title');
        $data['date'] = $this->input->post('date');
        $data['lastdate'] = $this->input->post('laastdatetoregister');
        $data['venue'] = $this->input->post('venuedetails');
        $data['contactperson'] = $this->input->post('contactperson');
        $data['emailid'] = $this->input->post('emailid');
        $data['contactnumber'] = $this->input->post('contactnumber');
        $data['status'] = 1;
        $data['id'] = $this->db->insert_id();
        print_r($data);
        $this->db->insert('jobmelas', $data);
        $jobmelaid = $this->db->insert_id();
        $jcdata['company'] = $this->input->post('company');
        $jcdata['jobtitle'] = $this->input->post('jobtitle');
        $jcdata['qualification'] = $this->input->post('qualification');
        $jcdata['specialization'] = $this->input->post('specialization');
        $jcdata['sector'] = $this->input->post('sector');
        $jcdata['jobtype'] = $this->input->post('jobtype');
        $this->insCompanies($jobmelaid, $jcdata);
    }
    public function insCompanies($jobmelaid, $jcdata, $update='') {
            if($update == 'update'){
                $this->db->query('delete from job_mela_companies where jobmelaid = '.$jobmelaid.'');
            }
            print_r($jcdata);
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($jcdata['company']); $i++) {
                $cp_data[] = array(
                    'jobmelaid' => $jobmelaid,
                    'company' => $jcdata['company'][$i],
                    'jobtitle' => $jcdata['jobtitle'][$i],
                    'qualification' => $jcdata['qualification'][$i],
                    'specialization' => $jcdata['specialization'][$i],
                    'jobtype' => $jcdata['jobtype'][$i],
                    'sector' => $jcdata['sector'][$i]
                );

                $this->db->insert('job_mela_companies', $cp_data);
            }
        }
```

First table is giving result correct but
The output of more fields giving like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below array and remove $cp_data[] = array(....) from insCompanies function.

```
$cp_data = array(
                'jobmelaid' => $jobmelaid,
                'company' => $jcdata['company'][$i],
                'jobtitle' => $jcdata['jobtitle'][$i],
                'qualification' => $jcdata['qualification'][$i],
                'specialization' => $jcdata['specialization'][$i],
                'jobtype' => $jcdata['jobtype'][$i],
                'sector' => $jcdata['sector'][$i]
                );
```

Comment: Sorry got same ressult

Comment: I tried to insert only one row. then it gives correct result in mysql, i mean whole characters i entered in input. but coming to multiple insertion it gives the last row and only one character of each input in mysql

Comment: use $cp_data instead $cp_data[]

Comment: Hi Dhara Ji,     when i tried this 'company' => $jcdata['company'][$i], it inserts only the first character, when i tried to remove [$i] it stores all the characters i entered, but multiple rows not inserted only the last row which is entred that only stores in mysql. if i tried to put $cp_data[ ] = array(...) this it stores multiple but all are stores as null values except the last row.

Comment: sorry multiple null values inserting when i tried to put insert_batch

Comment: here is the link of screenshot for null values ressult check it once

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14qrXIFhdEA3rWg1Cn345JGd9pMvbpYtu/view?usp=sharing

Comment: may be when you are getting multiple rows, you are getting different data format in $jcdata

Comment: Sorry @Dhara Bhalala, I forgot to insert array in view section  name="company[]".

Comment: Thanks for your Support